# My application crashes when asynctask process the code in android studio

Tags: java, mysql, runtime-error

When i click the login button to process and check my codes it closes the whole app..

logcat error

```
  08-30 00:48:33.876 20672-20672/com.map.laurence.crms2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.map.laurence.crms2, PID: 20672
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.map.laurence.crms2.BackgroundWorker.onPostExecute(BackgroundWorker.java:80)
                                                                            at com.map.laurence.crms2.BackgroundWorker.onPostExecute(BackgroundWorker.java:22)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:692)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:709)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
```

this class is my problem

BackgroundWorker.java

```
    package com.map.laurence.crms2;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.map.laurence.crms2.Menu;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://192.168.8.101/AndroidDB/login.php";

        if(type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("user_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result.equals("login success")) {
          context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Menu.class));
        }else{
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

login.java

```
 package com.map.laurence.crms2;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
public EditText user,pass;
    static Login login;
    private static final String TAG = "Login";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        login = this;
      user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUser);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPass);

    }

    public static Login getInstance(){
        return   login;
    }

    public void onLogin(View v){

        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();

        if(username == null || username.equals("") || password == null || password.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Empty Fields!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else
        {

            String type = "login";
            BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
            backgroundWorker.execute(type, username, password);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


        Log.d("back button", "back button pressed");
        AlertDialog.Builder ad1=new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
        ad1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Exit? ");
        ad1.setCancelable(false);


        ad1.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {


            }
        });

        ad1.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert=ad1.create();
        alert.show();


    }

}
```

ive tried clicking the button for toast message and it doesnt crashes.

ive tried replacing this

```
 super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result.equals("login success")) {
      context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Menu.class));
    }else{
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

with this

```
 super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result.equals("login success")) {
         alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }else{
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

but it gave me the "login Status" from here

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }
```

and no dialog response from the server please help me thanks

here is the login.xml file for those who wanna try it out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/backg"

    tools:context="com.map.laurence.crms2.Login">



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/title"



            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logoo"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Apalit Portable" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:text="Census Application" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="292dp"
        android:layout_height="265dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etUser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/text_edge"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/username"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etPass"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_edge"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"

            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:onClick="onLogin"
            android:background="@drawable/button_file"
            android:textAlignment="center"

            />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

every help will much be appreciated thanks

Comment: make sure `result` is not `null` , use logs to verify it

Comment: just an hour ago that runs perfectly .. but after i reboot my computer that error started appearing

Comment: please apply the precious comment , quite sure `result ` is null , probably some some server or internet issue